# Individual CSS spoiler without javascript

Tags: css

A website use this spoiler code:

https://codepen.io/oloman/pen/odnqy

```css
input[id^="spoiler"] {
  display: none;
}

input[id^="spoiler"]+label {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background: #e1a;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .6s;
}

input[id^="spoiler"]:checked+label {
  color: #333;
  background: #ccc;
}

input[id^="spoiler"]~.spoiler {
  width: 90%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: all .6s;
}

input[id^="spoiler"]:checked+label+.spoiler {
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="spoiler" />
<label for="spoiler">Spoiler1</label>
<div class="spoiler">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Etiam congue, neque a commodo
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="spoiler" />
<label for="spoiler">Spoiler1</label>
<div class="spoiler">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Etiam congue, neque a commodo
</div>
```

This works, when only 1 spoiler is visible. If multiple spoilers are available, only the first one is working (opening), when someone click at the next buttons.

Is there a way to make this individual without javascript and only with css, maybe with hasChild? Its not possible to use different ID´s.

I made a jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/swj38nmr/

Comment: ID's must be UNIQUE...you can't re-use them  Use a class instead.

Comment: Its not possible to use different IDs in this case

Comment: Your checkbox IDs can have a number appended at the end of it as your selectors are targeting `input` elements that have the `id` attribute set to start with `spoiler`. You also have to update your `label` elements to point to the correct `input` elements.

Comment: Why can't you use different ID's? It's invalid HTML otherwise.

Comment: Because its a bbcode in a forum.

Comment: Then you'll need JS..

Comment: Also your Codepen uses different ID..but your JS fiddle does not...pick one!

Comment: You need to configure your HTML, and wrap your input, label and div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve this effect -without *javascript*- using the html element `details` and a css keyframe:

Simplest example:

```css
details[open] summary ~ * {
  animation: spoiler 1s ease-in-out;
  padding: 2rem;
  background: pink;
  border-radius: 1rem
}

@keyframes spoiler {
  0%    {opacity: 0; background: red; border-radius: 3rem}
  100%  {opacity: 1; background: pink; border-radius: 1rem}
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    Spoiler
  </summary>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eu sodales tortor, posuere mattis nunc. Integer eget sapien ullamcorper diam mollis laoreet. Praesent dignissim id urna at malesuada. Etiam id nisl vitae ante vestibulum volutpat.
    </p>
</details>

<details>
  <summary>
    Spoiler
  </summary>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eu sodales tortor, posuere mattis nunc. Integer eget sapien ullamcorper diam mollis laoreet. Praesent dignissim id urna at malesuada. Etiam id nisl vitae ante vestibulum volutpat.
    </p>
</details>

<details>
  <summary>
    Spoiler
  </summary>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eu sodales tortor, posuere mattis nunc. Integer eget sapien ullamcorper diam mollis laoreet. Praesent dignissim id urna at malesuada. Etiam id nisl vitae ante vestibulum volutpat.
    </p>
</details>
```

Behave well on mobile.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details